# Passing JS Object into HTML String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a JS variable, that defines a DOM element that I want to show somewhere else on the DOM,  defined as

`var salesRep = $("ul.map").attr("id","1");`

And I want to pass it to a function called `show();`

So I made

```
function getSalesRep(salesRep){
 return salesRep
 }
```

Then inside the `show()` function I called `getSalesRep()`

Which looks like

```
function show(){
   getSalesRep();  
   var x1 = "<p>" + salesRep + "<p>";
   $("#map").after($(x1));
   }
```

However on the DOM, where the `salesRep` variable that contains HTML should  appear, it outputs `[Object object]`

I can seem to figure it out...I am convinced it has something to do with the way I am defining the object wrong.

Comment: How will `salesRep` look in the DOM

Comment: try using JSON.stringify(salesRep) and in the function definition use JSON.parse(salesRep);

Comment: Ummmm. How is `getSalesRep();` going to return anything other than `undefined`? It returns the input passed to it, and you haven't passed any. Doh!

Comment: @brk it should look like HTML text like `Hello World'

Comment: to get the html of any jquery object use the .html() method. Try salesRep.html()

Comment: @enhzflep thanks! how would i pass it?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not going to speculate, without seeing a minimal, complete example. There's too many things I'd be guessing at presently. Sorry.

Comment: What do you expect `$("ul.map").attr("id","1");` to do? I have the feeling it isn't what you expect? Please show your HTML or better still provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 3):

In case if you need html content to show there,

```
var x1 = "<p>" + salesRep.html() + "<p>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Before appending the DOM element,you need to `JSON.stringify` the `[Object object]`

```
function show(){
  let listOfSales = JSON.stringify(getSalesRep());  
  var x1 = "<p>" + listOfSales + "<p>";
  $("#map").after($(x1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you concatenate string and objects. You need to stringify the salesRep and concatenate.

You can use JSON.stringify() to achieve the same.

Once you have the string you can add it as an inner HTML of a newly created element and append it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a function to access the variable `salesRep`. Defining the `getSalesRep`, and then calling it is not necessary here as its not doing anything. If you remove function definition and call from show method nothing will be affected, As you are using the `salesRep` variable in the end. You just have to use stringify `salesRep` the object using the `.html()` method on it.